# Image appears like a broken image

Tags: python, django

The problem is that I get a broken image type. My code is as follows:

in settings.py I have

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')]

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/work_station/project1/media/static/pic'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

My models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/pic/', default = None)
    description  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
```

My views

```
class IndexListView(ListView):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"
    context_object_name = 'latest_pictures'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Image.objects.all()
    return str(self.image)
```

my template: dashboard.html

```
{% for latest in latest_pictures %}
{% load staticfiles %}
        <div><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ latest.image }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what is the broken link?

Comment: And what is responsible for serving files from /media/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, your `MEDIA_ROOT` should be

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and Image files are not staticfiles, they are media files. so..

```
{% for latest in latest_pictures %}
    <div><img src="{{ latest.image.url }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

should be good enough.

and btw, `upload_to` is a destination under `media` folder. `upload_to='static/pic/'` is kind of misleading name..

aaand as Daniel stated, if your server is serving your media files correctly, then this should work.

Comment: Oh, how fool of me. I just read the difference between static files and media files before posting this question here and I didnt thought for changing my template code. That works perfectly fine now. Many thanks to you.